# Get user posts with custom WP_Query on author.php

Tags: wp-query, author-template

I try to show custom post list with WP_Query on author.php like this:

```php
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'author' => 'get_queried_object_id()', 'posts_per_page' => 9 );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        
<figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : the_post_thumbnail(); endif; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a></figure>
<h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>

                
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        
        <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'No posts by this author' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It gives posts from all authors for some reason. I've tried different combinations of 'author' array element with no luck or some other errors/issues (like displaying only one post for example).

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Try to remove single quotes here: `'get_queried_object_id()'`

Comment: anton, now it shows only one post by the actual author.

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1 post per this author? Just checked your code on my wp, works fine and shows more than 1 post per author)

Comment: Sorry, you're right - it works! It's my mistake with another author that has only one post... Thank you!

Comment: I will add it as an answer, if you do not mind. Let's remove this question from unanswered list)

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using the `pre_get_posts` filter to change the main query on author pages? Replacing the main query with a custom one means you've got to reinvent all the things WP did for you such as pagination, worse performance, and weird problems, e.g. if your query has a page 4 but the main query only has 3 pages, WP might return a 404 for the 4th page

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, I'm newcomer in PHP and WP coding so yes will learn pre_get_posts too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in single quotes will be interpret as string. 
You just need to remove single quotes in your `$args` array.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'author' => get_queried_object_id(), //remove single quotes here
    'posts_per_page' => 9 
);
```